# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, windows-server-2012

I have `windows server 2012` with sql server database. I install xampp for running php scripts with php pdo modules.

this php app worked normally in other system with `windows server 2008` but here I have this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. ' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\app...\index.php:20 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\app...\index.php(20):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=1...', 'username', 'pass') #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app...\index.php on line 20

any idea?

Comment: Is this instance of SQL Server local or remote?

Comment: @Zhorov this is remote connection

Comment: Can you connect to this instance using SQL Server Management Studio or with some other tool?

Comment: yes I can connect with sql server tools. this problem occur just in pdo connection

Comment: What is your server connection string - something like "server\instance,port"?

Comment: @Zhorov `$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=192.168.2.100,31106;Database={$database}", "{$user}", "{$pass}");`

Comment: Check the port number. If you have MS SQL Server Management Studio, execute: xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on' in master database.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4a8d822f-83b5-4eac-a38c-6c963b386343/query-timing-out?forum=sqldriverforphp

Comment: Any fix yet? How many transactions are happening to the database concurrently?